# Init localStorage after every refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I would like to initialize localStorage object every time a user does a refresh by F-5.

Can i do such a thing?

The localStorage object is working fine by setItem and getItem methods.
However, I would like to know if i have the option to init this object every refresh action.

For example:
I have two different pages in my app. A.js and B.js.
When loading B.js i set the localStorage:

```
var id = getId();
window.localStorage.setItem("Id", id );
```

After that when i clicking on a button for going to A.js i am doing:

```
var selectedId = window.localStorage.getItem("Id");

if (selectedId !== null){
    var intSelectedId = parseInt(selectedId );
   //DO LOGIC
 }
```

I would like to delete ("Id", id) key-value pair every refresh.
How can i do it?

Comment: Init what, and how? It's not at all clear what you're asking ?

Comment: What do you mean by initing localStorage?

Comment: Do you mean like `var initID = localStorage.getItem("id") || getId();` like everyone else I'm sort of stumped to what you are asking exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this ?

```
//declare in global scope
var myinitvalue = "blah";
//handle what happens just before page unloads
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem("Id", myinitvalue);
}
```

Unfortunately the side effect of this is that the value will also reset if browser tab is closed or if back button is clicked.

Comment: It helps in several cases and in several not! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, i think this particular DOM event handler should do the trick. If you think my answer sufficiently answered your question, please select as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete item with key `Id` once your page is loaded, do

```
window.onload=function(){
   localStorage.removeItem("Id");
}
```